# Over-current issue on USB port - ignore_oc flag not working

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, dvd

I have connected Lenovo's DVD RW to my linux system (kernel - 2.6.34). The kernel is disconnecting the writer with overcurrent issue.

kern.log -

```
Feb  9 14:09:53 base0-0-0-11-0-11-1 kernel: hub 2-1:1.0: over-current change on port 1
```

I turned on ignore_oc flag but i am still receving the errors and my DVD is not being detected.

```
root@base0-0-0-11-0-11-1:/root> cat /sys/module/ehci_hcd/parameters/ignore_oc
Y
root@base0-0-0-11-0-11-1:/root>
```

kern.log -

```
Feb  9 14:09:53 base0-0-0-11-0-11-1 kernel: ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00, overcurrent ignored
```

Can someone pls help?

Thanks.